# How can I route traffic from my main wired router to the wireless computers on the other side of a connected Wi-Fi router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, routing, wireless-router

I have a router that takes my Verizon FiOS as input and has five output ports. The main internal IP address of the router is *192.168.0.1*.

From one of the ports on the wired router, I have my Wi-Fi router connected, and it has an IP address of *192.168.0.10*. The other ports on the wired router all have *192.168.0.x* IP addresses.

On the other side of the Wi-Fi router, the wireless IP addresses are of the form *192.168.1.x*.

From the Wi-Fi network I **can** get to the *192.168.0.x* wired IP addresses, but I **cannot** get to the *192.168.1.x* wireless IP addresses from the wired network.

So, I believe I need to make a change in the Wi-Fi router to allow traffic from the *192.168.0.x* wired IP addresses into the *192.168.1.x* wireless IP addresses. Is this correct?

What do I need to look for in order to make this change (e.g., wireless settings, LAN settings, WAN settings, etc.)? Once there, what type of change should I make?

Comment: You have two router-type devices on two different subnets:  .0 and .1  .   Try to get the wireless router on 192.168.0.x   and not .1 . That will help you get internet also.

Comment: @John The internet works perfectly, I have no issues other than not being able to access computers on the `192.168.1.x` network from the `192.168.0.x` network.

Comment: You need to get everything on one subnet for smooth operation of internet, device (folder) sharing and printing. I do that here - all devices including phones are on one subnet. I have two physical areas and found a way to route Ethernet between the two areas which greatly eases things.

Comment: @John, not necessarily as they might be on a /16 subnet mask. Without that information it’s impossible to say if the devices are on different subnets or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set up the device you're calling your "Wi-Fi router" to act as a simple Wi-Fi AP instead of acting as a router.

Some wireless router devices allow you to disable their NAT gateway and DHCP server features, and will automatically make their WAN Ethernet port act like a LAN Ethernet port. Others don't have this option, but you can still accomplish the same thing by not using the WAN port (connect the Ethernet cable from the LAN port of the upstream router to a LAN port of the downstream router), and by disabling the DHCP server feature if possible, or setting its DHCP IP address lease pool to be zero length (so it has no addresses it can lease out via DHCP).

By hooking things up this way, your home network becomes one single LAN with a single IP subnet.

Comment: It may also be called "bridge mode"

Answer (score 7):

@Spiff answer is generally the best one (and I upvoted it).  If you do have some reason you need to have two separate networks joined together, there is an alternative -

1. Change the netmask for the LAN on each router to 255.255.255.0 if its not set to that already.
2. Assign the Wi-Fi router WAN interface a static IP address. You can either do this as a [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) assignment in the wired router or by a static assignment in the Wi-Fi router. The address needs to be in the 192.168.0 range.
3. On the wires router, add a route to 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 via the IP address assigned to the Wi-Fi router above.
4. Depending on the smarts in your Wi-Fi router, you may need to disable [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation).

Answer (score 1):

I would echo suggestions to use a single subnet method by connecting your Wi-Fi router via LAN port instead of WAN port to the wired segment of your network (and disable [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) on the Wi-Fi router). This will keep Wi-Fi devices on the 192.168.0.x subnet, thereby avoiding routing. Generally speaking, that would simplify things. But if you insist on keeping two subnets then there are two problems to tackle:

1. Setting up your Wi-Fi router appropriately to route packets.
   You will want to disable firewall / [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) and set it to a static IP address if it isn't already. Depending on the router model/firmware, there may be an option to do all that by turning on "router only" mode or something similar.
2. Tell your hosts on the 192.168.0.x subnet that they need to use 192.168.0.10 as a gateway to reach hosts on the 192.168.1.x subnet. This information is typically distributed via DHCP.

a) So the preferred method would be to add a static route information to your Verizon router.

b) Alternatively you could set up a DHCP server on a device (like [Raspberry Pi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi)) on your 192.168.0.x network and configure DHCP to dish out correct routing information, essentially replacing the DHCP function of your Verizon router. You will of course would want to disable DHCP on your Verizon router.

c) One last option - last resort - add a static route on each 192.168.0.x host manually using the command line. This will be doable on Windows or Linux boxes, but it might be a challenge for phones or TVs.